# Assembly vs. algorithmic languages (like C, Algol, etc)

Tags: algorithms, assembly, taocp

Usually, computer science papers describe algorithms in Algol-like pseudolanguage, similar to Pascal or even C/C++.

But Donald Knuth uses his own assembly language (MMIX).

Are there any good known algorithms inexpressible in Algol-like language but expressible in unstructured assembly code? Like coroutines, maybe?

Comment: They are both [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) and thus can express all of the same problems.  It might be a bit more wordy or awkward in one style, but it can still be done.

Comment: @MichaelT Turing equivalence is about computability. In algorithm textbooks, we are also interested in complexity, which depends on the model of computation. Algol-style performance and machine code performance usually *are* within constant factors of each other. But not merely because both are Turing complete.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Knuth himself gives an answer in "The Art of Computer Programming".

He says:

> High level languages are inadequate for discussing important low-level
>   details such as coroutine linkage, random number generation,
>   multi-precision arithmetic, and many problems involving the efficient
>   usage of memory.

But the decision to use a machine-oriented language is probably due to the fact that:

> New algebraic languages go in and out of fashion every five years or
>   so, while I am trying to emphasize concepts that are timeless.

<sup>(Preface to TAOCP vol. 1)</sup>

---

> Moreover, if I did use a high-level language, what language should it be? In
>   the 1960s I would probably have chosen Algol W; in the 1970s, I would then
>   have had to rewrite my books using Pascal; in the 1980s, I would surely have
>   changed everything to C; in the 1990s, I would have had to switch to C++ and
>   then probably to Java. In the 2000s, yet another language will no doubt be
>   *de rigueur*. I cannot afford the time to rewrite my books as languages go in
>   and out of fashion; languages aren't the point of my books, the point is
>   rather what you can do in your favorite language. My books focus on timeless
>   truths.
>
> ---
>
> Expressing basic methods like algorithms for sorting and searching in machine
>   language makes it possible to carry out meaningful studies of the effects of
>   cache and RAM size and other hardware characteristics (memory speed,
>   pipelining, multiple issue, lookaside buffers, the size of cache blocks,
>   etc.) when comparing different schemes.

Indeed since *'60* there were suitable notation for coroutines in ALGOL-like languages:

> ...coroutine linkage had already been noted briefly as a "programming tip" in
>   an early UNIVAC publication [...] A suitable notation for coroutines in
>   ALGOL-like languages was introduced in Dahl and Nygaard's SIMULA I [...] and
>   several excellent examples of coroutines (including replicated coroutines)
>   appear in the book Structured Programming [by Dahl, Dijkstra, and Hoare].

<sup>(TAOCP vol. 1, pp 229-230)</sup>

Not to mention high-precision / multiple precision routine in FORTRAN / ALGOL:

> Extended precision subroutines for use in FORTRAN programs were described by
>   B.I. Blum (1965) [...] and for use in ALGOL by M. Tienari and V.Suokonautio
>   [...]
>   Arithmetic on integers with *unlimited* precision, making use of linked memory allocation techniques, was elegantly introduced by G.E. Collins [...]

<sup>(TAOCP vol. 2, pg 279)</sup>

Same about random number generation: there are examples in C (TAOCP vol. 2, pp 185-188) and exercises in other high level languages (e.g. [EX10] pg 193).